# Why does the number 1e9999... (31 9s) cause problems in R?

Tags: r

When entering `1e9999999999999999999999999999999` into R, R hangs and will not respond -  requiring it to be terminated.

It seems to happen across 3 different computers, OSes (Windows 7 and Ubuntu). It happens in RStudio, RGui and RScript.

Here's some code to generate the number more easily:

```
boom <- paste(c("1e", rep(9, 31)), collapse="")
eval(parse(text=boom))
```

Now clearly this isn't a practical problem. I have no need to use numbers of this magnitude. It's just a question of curiosity.

Curiously, if you try `1e9999999999999999999999999999998` or `1e10000000000000000000000000000000` (add or subtract one from the power), you get `Inf` and `0` respectively. This number is clearly some kind of boundary, but between what and why here?

I considered that it might be:

- A floating point problem, but I think they max out at  1.7977e308, long before the number in question.
- An issue with 32-bit integers, but 2^32 is 4294967296, much smaller than the number in question.
- Really weird. This is my dominant theory.

EDIT: As of 2015-09-15 at the latest, this no longer causes R to hang. They must have patched it.

Comment: Love the dominant theory! By the way - this happens to me too. Maybe a memory thing?

Comment: Even better: `boom <- paste(c("10^", rep(9, 31)), collapse="")` works :P

Comment: That's interesting. It seems that `1e9...` doesn't work very well, but `1^9...` works fine.

Comment: @sebastian-c That's not surprising, since `1e9...` and `1^9...` are different numbers.

Comment: http://www.validlab.com/goldberg/paper.pdf  http://cran.at.r-project.org/web/packages/Brobdingnag/vignettes/brobpaper.pdf

Comment: @ChrisTaylor My apologies, a moment of profound density. However, it does seem that if I replace the `1` in `1e9...` with any 1 digit integer, the same thing happens. It also happens if I use `1.5`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This looks like an extreme case in the parser.  The `XeY` format is described in [Section 10.3.1: Literal Constants](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Literal-constants) of the [R Language Definition](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html) and points to `?NumericConstants` for "up-to-date information on the currently accepted formats".

The problem seems to be how the parser handles the exponent.  The numeric constant is handled by `NumericValue` (line 4361 of `main/gram.c`), which calls `mkFloat` (line 4124 of `main/gram.c`), which calls `R_atof` (line 1584 of `main/util.c`), which calls `R_strtod4` (line 1461 of `main/util.c`).  (All as of revision 60052.)

Line 1464 of `main/utils.c` shows `expn` declared as `int` and it will overflow at line 1551 if the exponent is too large.  The signed integer overflow causes undefined behavior.

For example, the code below produces values for exponents < 308 or so and `Inf` for exponents > 308.

```
const <- paste0("1e",2^(1:31)-2)
for(n in const) print(eval(parse(text=n)))
```

You can see the undefined behavior for exponents > 2^31 (R hangs for an exponent = 2^31):

```
const <- paste0("1e",2^(31:61)+1)
for(n in const) print(eval(parse(text=n)))
```

I doubt this will get any attention from R-core because R can only store numeric values between about 2e-308 to 2e+308 (see `?double`) and this number is *way* beyond that.

Comment: I fear that the set of things for which _"doubt this will get any attention from R-core"_ is constantly growing.  I sent two mails in the last few weeks and got zero replies. :-/

Comment: Between that set and the "I would ask R-core this question (or submit this patch) but I'm sure I'd get roundly spanked" set, it's tough for me to work up much gumption to participate.

Comment: I would hope that *any* overflow, no matter the context, would be considered patchworthy though.

Comment: @KenWilliams: I'm thinking about submitting a patch, but I need to do some testing first... which will take some time, since it requires rebuilding R. I've been "Ripley'd" a few times; it's not too bad... better than being ignored. ;)

Comment: If it's an integer overflow, shouldn't issues be at 2147483647 rather than 9...?

Comment: @sebastian-c: issues should occur with any exponent > 2147483647.  I actually get a hang for `1e2147483647`, and `1e2147483648 = 0`, while `1e2147483646 = Inf` (as expected).

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich It does for me too and it seems that the it wraps around as would be expected for an overflow.

Comment: I think I can see what is special about 31 9's. It is exactly one less that 10^32 and 10 has 2 as a factor. So there is a 2^32 in there just waiting to cause trouble. 9999999999999999999999999999999 is 2^31-1 which is 2147483647 after overflow. The result of overflow is modulus, or the remainder after repeated integer division. (10^31-1)/(2^32) = (2^31*5^31)/2^32 - 1/2^32 = 5^31/2 - 1/2^32 = (5^31-1) + 1/2 - 1/2^32. Take off the quotient of 5^31-1 leaves a fractional part of (2^31-1)/2^32 which is a remainder of 2^31-1 or 2147483647.

Answer (score 5):

This is interesting, but I think R has systemic problems with parsing numbers that have very large exponents:

```
> 1e10000000000000000000000000000000
[1] 0
> 1e1000000000000000000000000000000
[1] Inf
> 1e100000000000000000000
[1] Inf
> 1e10000000000000000000
[1] 0
> 1e1000
[1] Inf
> 1e100
[1] 1e+100
```

There we go, finally something reasonable. According to this output and Joshua Ulrich's comment below, R appears to support representing numbers up to about 2e308 and parsing numbers with exponents up to about +2*10^9, but it cannot represent them. After that, there is undefined behavior apparently due to overflow.

Comment: It can _parse_ numeric constants with exponents +/-2*10^9, but it cannot _represent_ them because double precision values are limited to about 2e-308 to 2e+308 (see `?double`).

Comment: I wouldn't say it was properly parsing them. The representation keeps changing between +Inf and 0 depending only on the number of digits in the exponent. If it were parsing properly it would either reject the input or map all these inputs to +Inf.

Comment: I only said it could parse exponents up to the signed integer bound and the result only changes between `0` and `Inf` once the exponent is larger than that and you overflow the exponent variable in the parser: `const <- paste0("1e",2^(10:32-1); for(n in const) print(eval(parse(text=n)))`.

Comment: Gotcha. So would it be fair to say the following? 1. It parses and represents up to about 2e+308. 2. It parses but cannot represent up to about 2e+2^32 so they become +Inf. 3. Beyond that the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Yes, that's my understand of what's happening.  Line 1446 of `main/utils.c` shows `expn` declared as `int` and it will overflow at line 1553 if `n` is too large, which will cause undefined behavior.

Comment: I just checked and now R seems to handle them as expected.

Answer (score 4):

*R* might use sometimes [bignums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bignums). Perhaps `1e9999999999999999999999999999999` is some threshold, or perhaps the parsing routines have a limited buffer for reading the exponent. Your observation would be consistent with a 32 char (null-terminated) buffer for the exponent.

I'll rather ask that question on forums or mailing list specific to *R*, which are rumored to be friendly.

Alternatively, since *R* is free software, you could investigate its source code.