# Is using RinRuby secure for web solutions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, r, security

I recall from some meetups I've attended in NYC that people in bell labs were trying to work on potential security issues with R on the web.  There was potential risks of code injection into a Web App if R sessions were kept alive for the user.

Now, this was presented in the context of HTML 5 and PHP, but I don't see how it would be different when using RoR with the RinRuby gem.  Is there a set of rules we as developers should follow to avoid common security pitfalls when using this gem?

Comment: Security vulnerabilities are usually a very specific implementation detail. You'd have to look at the exact context of the particular vulnerability to see if/how it translates. However, *any system with external access is potentially comprisable*. (Searching *should* reveal which vulnerabilities have affected said web-framework, if they are patched/corrected, and how they can be mitigated.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R in general was not built with security in mind (see also this [preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.4808) at arXiv by Jeroen Ooms). It is also notorious for [flaky parsing of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700748/why-does-the-number-1e9999-31-9s-cause-problems-in-r).

Judging from the source code (which was [not updated for 2 years](https://github.com/clbustos/rinruby/blob/master/lib/rinruby.rb) (!)) RinRuby doesn't seem to provide any kind of isolation from injection either - bare-bones `eval` is a gateway to hell, they say :)

Thus, it falls upon your shoulders to follow e.g. [OWASP guidelines](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) to avoid injection by carefully validating, parameterizing and whitelisting the input. Having in mind the above-mentioned quirks in parsing numbers, you have to restrict inputs to sane intervals.

Just my 2 cents...

Comment: Thanks @DeerHunter.  I printed a copy of Ooms' paper.  That's pretty much the information I was looking for.  I see it can be a big pain to securely deploy R solutions for the web, so I will only use Ruby for that purpose.